# htaccess for multiple pages doesn't works

Tags: regex, .htaccess, web, mod-rewrite

Start by explaining what I'm trying to do:
I've got different pages on my website. Some pages have the same templates so I create one page with parameters to adapt my page: Parameters are called pageview and lang the URL looks like this:
http://mywebsite/home/en <- http://mywebsite/index.php?pageview=home&lang=en
http://mywebsite/page2/fr <- http://mywebsite/index.php?pageview=page2&lang=fr
for example. To dot that, I use the famous .htaccess file and it module rewrite_module for Apache.
I've got also a contact page with a different template. It URL looks like this and here there is only one parameter:
http://mywebsite/contact/fr <- http://mywebsite/contact.php?lang=fr
http://mywebsite/contact/en <- http://mywebsite/contact.php?lang=en

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^contact/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ contact.php?lang=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?pageview=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?pageview=$1&lang=$2 [QSA]
```

The problem is that `.htaccess` file work for the index.php but not for `contact.php`

I can fully access to `contact.php` but the parameter is not detected

Thanks for your help  !

**EDIT**

If I remove index parts to stay only the contact rewriteRule's the problem stay there.
`contact.php` and `index.php` are in the root folder

Comment: Have you tried to add `[QSA]`?

Comment: Yes but nothing change ;(

Comment: Try `[L]` to stop the rules processing. You might also want to make it case-insensitive and ensure you punt to *contact.php* at the document root, e.g.: `RewriteRule ^contact/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /contact.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: there is still the problem but thanks anyway

Comment: my PHP code seems working because when I type (http://mywebsite/contact.php?lang=fr) it works perfectly

Comment: [It should work](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=a147f3b9-942d-517b-813e-0a42c3b5a866) unless there's something we're not seeing...

Comment: I'm working in local with wamp64 maybe something wrong whit it? Is XAMPP better?

Comment: It doesn't work also when I put my conde into an OVH server

Comment: despite that, I use XAMPP the problem still there 

Comment: does it exist some parameters into apache that can make ```.htaccess``` file not working well?

Comment: Finally, I think I will use $_SESSION object in my PHP code. It's like cookies but data are erased after the web page is closed

Comment: @Lolix, stop cluttering everything with your emoji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^contact/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ contact.php?lang=$1
> ```

It looks like you may have a conflict with MultiViews. If MultiViews is enabled then mod_negotiation will rewrite a request for `/contact/fr` to `/contact.php` (without any parameters) *before* mod_rewrite is able to process the request.

Try disabling MultiViews at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```